# why floating point exception in OpenCL kernel call to sin but not cos?

Tags: floating-point, opencl

My OpenCL kernel is throwing a floating point exception. I've reduced it to just the lines I think are causing the problem.

If I replace the line

```
acc.x += sin(distSqr);
```

with

```
acc.x += cos(distSqr);
```

or

```
acc.x += sqrt(distSqr);
```

or just

```
acc.x += (distSqr);
```

The kernel runs fine. Why?
NB: My global work size is divisible by my local work size.

Thanks.

Here's the kernel:

```
__kernel void compute_forces(
                      __global float3 *x3a,
                      __global float3 *p3a,
                      __global float3 *x3b,
                      __global float3 *p3b,
                      __global float3 *f3a,
                      float dt,
                      float qQa,
                      float qQb,
                      float qma,
                      float qmb,
                      int n0a,
                      int n1a,
                      int n0b,
                      int n1b,
                      float xmin,
                      float ymin,
                      float epsSqr,
                      float force_fac,
                        __local float3 *localx
                      )
{


//we are going to compute the force between parts (n0a-n1a) and (n0b-n1b)
//Each particle loads the particle in the current block into local memory, so
unsigned int tid = get_local_id(0);
unsigned int gid = get_global_id(0);

unsigned int ninter=0;

// position of this work-item
float3 myPos = x3a[gid];
float3 acc = (float3)(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


    // Synchronize to make sure data is available for processing
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);


    for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {

        float3 r=-myPos;
        float distSqr = r.x * r.x;


        // accumulate effect of all particles
        acc.x += sin(distSqr);

        ninter++;

    }//j

    // Synchronize so that next tile can be loaded
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);



f3a[gid]+=acc;
f3a[gid].x=(float)ninter;

}
```

I call the kernel like:

```
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 0, sizeof(_x3), &_x3);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 1, sizeof(_p3), &_p3);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 2, sizeof(_x3), &_x3);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 3, sizeof(_p3), &_p3);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 4, sizeof(_f3), &_f3);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 5, sizeof(dt_float), &dt_float);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 6, sizeof(qQa), &qQa);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 7, sizeof(qQb), &qQb);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 8, sizeof(qma), &qma);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces, 9, sizeof(qmb), &qmb);
    err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,10, sizeof(n0a), &n0a);
    err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,11, sizeof(n1a), &n1a);
    err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,12, sizeof(n0b), &n0b);
    err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,13, sizeof(n1b), &n1b);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,14, sizeof(xmin_float), &xmin_float);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,15, sizeof(ymin_float), &ymin_float);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,16, sizeof(epsSqr), &epsSqr);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,17, sizeof(force_fac), &force_fac);
err=clSetKernelArg(k_compute_forces,18, parts_per_block*sizeof(cl_float3),NULL);

    err=clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, k_compute_forces, work_dim, NULL, global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, NULL, &k_compute_forces_completion);
```

EDIT: I think the sin function cannot handle float's smaller than about 1.0e-12 because the line:

```
acc.x += sin(1.0e-12);
```

runs fine but

```
acc.x += sin(1.0e-13);
```

Throws an exception. This would seem to suggest sin_half is being called instead of sin...I wonder if this is a replacement made by the optimization.

If I add in a printf statement right before the above line

```
printf("distSqr=%g\n",distSqr);
```

then the error changes from "floating point exception" to something about "divisionErrorHandler" (though it's hard to make out because the output text is jumbled up).

Comment: Info regarding the error you are getting and the OpenCL SDK version (CPU or GPU)used will be useful.

Comment: The error is "Floating point exception (core dumped)" and I'm compiling on my Intel i7.

Comment: I think it's the Nvidia SDK 4.2 I'm using.

Comment: sin(x) = x for x<<1 so as a hack you could try acc.x += x <<1.0e-12 ? x : sin(x);

Comment: I mean acc.x += x <1.0e-12 ? x : sin(x);

Comment: Nice hack :) , but my real kernel is much more compilcated than the short version I've posted above, and it will involve many more math functions than just sin so I think I need to get to the root of this.

Answer (score 0):

Since sin(x) does not seem to be working for small values of x, my suspicion is that the Nvidia driver is replacing it with native_sin(x), which evaluates to a function directly implemented in the hardware, but which may not be that accurate or support the full range of numbers.  I suggest adding the build option "-cl-opt-disable" to the call to clBuildProgram as this should disable all optimisations, telling us if the compiler optimisations are at fault.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Could it be because I'm using the Nvidia SDK but running on my Intel i7? (I no longer have an Nvidia card).

Comment: Hm, I missed that.  My experience mixing Nvidia and AMD GPUs says that using the Nvidia lib files and header files should be fine.  But, I would suggest the following: first switch to using the Intel SDK headers and lib file.  If that doesn't fix it, try downloading the AMD APP SDK.  If that one also gives you the same problem then your code is at fault somehow.

Comment: I agree with chippies.  I would also try running on the CPU using the AMD OpenCL drivers rather than the Intel one.  Rather than being a problem with the SDK the problem could be with the Intel's OpenCL driver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm going to install the other SDK's on separate machines because last time I had multiple SDK's on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04) it caused problems. In the meantime all I can add is that occasionally I get possibly a more meaningful error: "Unhandled signal in divisionErrorHandler()".

Comment: You should also test on your CPU, the AMD SDK does allow OpenCL code to run on Intel CPUs.